# Failing to fetch data from Swagger API doc

Tags: php, laravel, swagger, swagger-ui, openapi

I just started working with swagger/openapi last night and I am trying to document API for a demo bookstore app but I am not able to fetch data from the api on swagger-ui.

Here's a link to the api doc [bookstore api doc](http://ztp-bookstore.herokuapp.com/api/documentation)

I have added annotations to the BookController like this

```
/**
 *  @OA\Schema(
 *      schema="Book",
 *      @OA\Property(property="title", type="string"),
 *      @OA\Property(property="author", type="string"),
 *      @OA\Property(property="description", type="string")
 *  )
 */
/**
 *  @OA\Schema(
 *      schema="NewBook",
 *      required={"title", "author", "description"}
 *  )
 */

class BookController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @OA\Get(
     *     path="/books",
     *     description="Returns a books list from the app",
     *     operationId="getBooksList",
     *     summary="Gets a complete list of all books available on the app with their ratings",
     *     @OA\Response(
     *         response=200,
     *         description="book response",
     *         @OA\JsonContent(
     *             type="array",
     *             @OA\Items(ref="#/components/schemas/Book")
     *         )
     *     ),
     *     @OA\Response(
     *         response="default",
     *         description="unexpected error",
     *     )
     * )
     */
    /**
     * Display a listing of the books.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return BookResource::collection(Book::with('ratings')->get());
    }
}
```

Where am I going wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: The OpenAPI definition specifies `http://my-default-host.com` and `https://projects.dev` as the target servers for requests. These servers don't exist, that's why you get "failed to fetch" errors from "try-it-out". Shouldn't the target server be `http://ztp-bookstore.herokuapp.com`? Can you post the part of your code that specifies the API server hostname?

Comment: Right, a friend just pointed that out to me now and I have made the change but when I push master to heroku, it still doesn't update the serve. Debugging that now.